# How to be certain that all threads have been killed upon pressing Ctrl+C

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ghci

I'm running a servant server and another background thread (via `async`) in **gchi**. When I press `Ctrl+c` on the GHCi prompt, the servant server shuts down properly, but my background thread keeps running. Only quitting the entire GHCi session seems to really terminate it.

Two questions:

- Is this behaviour only because I'm in GHCi? If I compiled a binary, ran it, and then pressed Ctrl+C on it, would the background-thread still keep running?
- How do I solve for this properly?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this behaviour only because I'm in GHCi? If I compiled a binary, ran it, and then pressed Ctrl+C on it, would the background-thread still keep running?

In a compiled binary, if ^C causes the `main` thread to end, then the process will end and all threads will also be (abruptly) ended as a side effect. It is not a given that ^C causes the `main` thread to end; see the discussion of signal handling below.

> How do I solve for this properly?

Probably you can catch the [`UserInterrupt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:UserInterrupt) exception to notice when ^C has been hit and shut down any threads you spawned in the exception handler.

I say "probably" because ^C handling is a bit complicated, and it's feasible that servant has installed custom handlers. In that case you may need to look into [signal handling](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Signals.html) via the `unix` package. (Dunno what the equivalent is for Windows systems.)