# How to get a list of threads in GHCi

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ghci

Is there any command that will list all background threads in a GHCi session? And next question is, how to kill one (or all) of them?

Related:

- [Is there a way to kill all forked threads in a GHCi session without restarting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999636/is-there-a-way-to-kill-all-forked-threads-in-a-ghci-session-without-restarting-i)
- [How to be certain that all threads have been killed upon pressing Ctrl+C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722102/how-to-be-certain-that-all-threads-have-been-killed-upon-pressing-ctrlc)

Comment: Why do you doubt the answer on the linked question? ("The library simply doesn't give you anything to get the `ThreadId`s of all (still running) threads or any other facility to work on any threads which doesn't belong to you.")

Comment: Not expecting the library to give me anything. Expecting some "hidden feature" in the RTS or GHCi.

Comment: The library is the collection of user-visible RTS features.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want the `ThreadId`s of running threads, it is your responsibility to keep track of them when you `forkIO`.